# Highcharts polar spider with multiple y-axis scale

Tags: charts, highcharts, data-visualization, spider-chart

I created a polar spider graph with highcharts http://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar-spider and I would like to know if it is possible to set scale (min and max) for each categories.

Comment: So you want the background grid to have different "length" to the center?

Comment: Not necessarily a different length but a different min and max, ie for a category A I have values ​​from 0 to 200 and for another category B from 0 to 1. Currently, category B, I do not see very well because the scale is 0 to 200. do you know how to do?

Comment: Unfortunatley it is not avilable, please request your idea to our [service](http://highcharts.uservoice.com)

Comment: @SebastianBochan Thanks, too bad. That's what I'll do.

Comment: Has there been any update on this issue?

Comment: Any update for this question @SebastianBochan?

Comment: @patL could you post a PoC of requested chart?

Comment: @SebastianBochan I'd like to know if there's a way to use different scales (e.g. from 0 to 1, and other from 0 to 20). [Here's](https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/world-cup-comparisons/isco-2018/) an example. Thank you

Comment: At this moment you can use variable pie chart: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/variable-radius-pie

Answer (score 1):

As Halvor Strand noted in his comment, one possible way to solve this question would be to have each of the chart points be a different distance from the center of the graph.

I chose to create a "dummy" line series to serve as the "lopsided" chart points, while making the real grid behind the lines invisible.

Here's the code for the "dummy" series:

```
    {
      name: 'dummy series for category max/mins',
      dataLabels: {
        allowOverlap: true,
        enabled: true,
        formatter:function() {
          return this.point.name;
        },
        style:{color:"black"}
      },
      data: [
        { y: 90000, name: 'Sales', dataLabels: { align: 'center', y: -5 } }, 
        { y: 70000, name: 'Marketing', dataLabels: { align: 'left', x: 10, y: 15 } },
        { y: 85000, name: 'Development', dataLabels: { align: 'left', x: 10, y: 15 } },
        { y: 80000, name: 'Customer Support', dataLabels: { align: 'center', y: 30 } },
        { y: 95000, name: 'Information<br />Technology', dataLabels: { align: 'right', x: -10, y: 15 } },
        { y: 100000, name: 'Administration', dataLabels: { align: 'right', x: -10, y: 15 } }
      ],
      pointPlacement: 'on',
      showInLegend: false,
      enableMouseTracking: false,
      lineWidth: 2,
      lineColor: 'red',
      marker: { enabled: false }
    }
```

What I did here is manually set the "max" values for each of the chart points and give them a name to match what would normally be shown in the x-axis categories.

The `dataLabels` attributes for all of the series return each data point's `name` attribute. Then, for each data point, there are unique `dataLabels` attributes to position the label.

To hide the gridlines and labels for the x- and y-axes, I added `gridLineWidth: 0` and `labels: { enabled: false }` to each.

Here's how the result appears:

[image]

A working fiddle with this example can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/bjrm0cr3/.